# How to configure modernizr to detetct drag and drop

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I'm trying to build a modernizr library that detects drag and drop. I have failed. What options from ***https://modernizr.com/download/?setclasses*** should I select?

Comment: I'm not sure if get your questions or what are you trying to archive here since "drag and drop" is not a feature from browsers. I think you are trying to detect touch events, since to me is more likely to match what you're looking for.

Comment: To drag and drop files into an HTML form for uploading. https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/ says to use the following code from modernizr: `var div = document.createElement('div');
return ('draggable' in div) || ('ondragstart' in div && 'ondrop' in div)`